# Unicast source address filtering in datagram socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I need to perform data filtering based on the source unicast IPv4 address of datagrams arriving to a Linux UDP socket.

Of course, it is always possible to manually perform the filtering based on the information provided by **recvfrom**, but I am wondering if there could be another more intelligent/efficient approach (if possible, not using libpcap).

Any ideas?

Comment: netfilter? Then the kernel will do it for you

Comment: @hexa: I am not familiar with NetFilter. Can I do my operations in user space?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read about iptables and netfilter and decide what you should do. www.netfilter.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a single source you need to allow, then use just **`connect(2)`** and kernel will do filtering for you. As a bonus, connected UDP sockets are more efficient. This, of cource, does not work for more then one source.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, NetFilter (the Linux firewall) can help you here.

You could also use the UDP options of [xinetd](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_xinetd.htm) and [tcpd](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tcpd.htm) to perform filtering.

Answer (score 0):

What proportion of datagrams are you expecting to discard? If it is very high, then you may want to review your application design (for example, to make the senders not send so many datagrams which are to be discarded). If it is not very high, then you don't really care about how much effort you spend discarding them.

Suppose discarding a packet takes the same amount of (runtime) effort as processing it normally; if you discard 1% of packets, you will only be spending 1% of time discarding. However, realistically, discarding is likely to be much easier than processing messages.

Comment: Actually the full purpose of the application is to make the difference between contributing sources with very similar traffic, and process only one of them.  This means, the discarded packets will at least be a 50%.